# Trying to deploy on Digitalocean, receiving error with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I have been following Gorail's tutorial to deploy on DigitalOcean. [See Here](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04#capistrano) and [Here also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=467&v=WBPV4vjzcjQ).

I've reached the part where I am using the cap production deploy in the command line, but I am getting the following error below, I am not understanding how this error is occuring:

```
luis@luis-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/mls2$ cap production deploy --trace
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rbenv
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/luis/Desktop/mls2/Capfile:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/usr/bin/cap:3:in `<main>'
```

This is my cap file:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"


# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/git"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'

require "capistrano/bundler"
require 'capistrano/rails'

# require "capistrano/chruby"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

and my production.rb :

```
set :production
server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user: 'USER', roles: %w{app db web}
```

and my gemfile, i've already added the capistrano gems in the development group as suggested in the video:

```
...    
group :development do
      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
      gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
      gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
      # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
      gem 'spring'
      gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
      gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.9', '>= 3.9.1'
      gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.3'
      gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
      gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1'
    end
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [that dependency](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv) by adding it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
```

Then `bundle install`.

Capistrano has started to shunt some of the lesser used features to optional modules lately.

Comment: I already had the gem installed, i forgot to add my gem file to the post, i've edited and added the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to require capistrano/passenger in your Capfile.

Comment: I was following the tutorial as mentioned originally and they stated it wasn't needed at the moment. Also, it's not related to my error and isn't relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not directly causing your problem, but you have a mistake in your Capfile. If you look at [the official documentation for capistrano-rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv#usage), the `set` commands are supposed to go in `deploy.rb`, not in `Capfile`. I suggest removing those lines and moving them to deploy.rb.

```
# Move to deploy.rb
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'
```

---

In any case, the error you are getting is likely due to the fact that the gem `capistrano-rbenv` can't be loaded. Here's what I would try:

1. Run `bundle exec cap production deploy`. All cap commands must be prefixed with `bundle exec`. Otherwise there is no guarantee that the Gemfile will be used.
2. If that doesn't work, run `bundle config without` to see if the `development` group of your Gemfile is being excluded by bundler. If so, remove that setting by running `bundle config --delete without`.

Answer (score 0):

Run Capistrano with `bundle exec cap production deploy`, in addition to making sure that the `capistrano-rbenv` gem is in your Gemfile, and `capistrano/rbenv` is in your Capfile as outlined in the other answers.